# Nagios to count files in certain Directory

Tags: windows-server-2012, monitoring, nagios

I am trying to monitor a directory on a server in which the amount of files can vary from day to day. This server itself is monitored fine on Nagios3.
However, if I want to count the number of files within a directory, for instance `d:\david\` , which are all XML files.

Can nagios do this, and if so how would I do it? I am newish to Nagios and still finding my feet with it.

Comment: What is your OS? From the provided path, it looks a Windows machine. You can write a script to count the files and invoke it from nagios via any available way (nrpe, http web page, ...).

Comment: the nagios server is ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the server being monitored in Windows server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nrpe` daemon (on the nagios server) to initiate a command on the remote host. In your Nagios `services.cfg` you might add a stanza which looks like this (change the `admins` contact group to a real contact group on your system.. or leave commented out?):

```
define service {
    service_description       count files in directory d:\david\
    check_command             count_david_files!
    host_name                 my.windows.host
    check_period              24x7
    notification_period       24x7
    # contact_groups            +admins
    event_handler_enabled     0
    use                       generic-service
}
```

Then, on `my.windows.host` you would have to find the `nrpe.cfg` file and add a line something like this (note: this is from a linux client but the configuration for windows is very similar)

```
command[count_david_files]=/usr/local/nagios/myplugins/check_david_files
```

The file `check_david_files` would need to be some kind of executable ([batch file works apparently](https://docs.nsclient.org/howto/external_scripts/)) which prints either "OK', "WARNING", "CRITICAL" or "UNKNOWN" and then exits with the corresponding exit code:

```
 OK (0), WARNING (1), CRITCAL (2) and UNKNOWN (3).
```

It is these exit coes which trigger the alert state in nagios to signal to the server somehting is amiss. It is in this batch file where you could do something like:

```
@echo "OK: Files less than 10"
@exit 0
```

or for a warning:

```
@echo "WARNING: Files > than 10!"
@exit 1
```

To start out with, you may want to use only those two lines for testing your setup. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script in any language you know/prefer to count the number of files in your directory. In this script, you can return specific exit status based on whether you want to consider the current state as OK, WARNING, or CRITICAL in nagios terms.

Then, you can use some tool like [NSClient++](https://www.nsclient.org/) or [Winrpe](https://itefix.net/winrpe) to call your script from nagios.